Extbase - Error - Trusted properties used outdated serialization format instead of json
After upgrading my site from 9.5 to LTS 10 and LTS 11, I have an Extbase error regarding the __trustedProperties argument in the Extbase URL. Extbase wants a Json but an old format is created.
Format
a:4:{s:9:"keywords";i:1;s:21:"theme";i:1;s:19:"program";i:1;s:5:"status";i:1;}df958SOMEHASH599

The error comes from class typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Controller/MvcPropertyMappingConfigurationService.php
The doc said

In general, __trustedProperties should work completely transparently
for you. You do not have to know how it works in detail. You have to
know this background knowledge only if you want to change data via
JavaScript or web services.

What can I do to avoid this error.

Please specify: When does the error appear? Generally or when sending a form? Did your website run on TYPO3 10 without the error? Did you follow the update instructions for both updates? For me this sounds like an outdated extension. Maybe a theme extension.

I found the cause of the error. A direct link with all the parameters of the version 9 extension had been added to certain action buttons. Thank you for your reply
